# simplessh library hangs when executing a command

Tags: haskell, ssh

I'm trying to use [simplessh](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplessh-0.2.0.5) library to run a sequence of commands over SSH (actually, to learn some Haskell). It seems to be going OK, but it hangs on the second `runSimpleSSH` in this code:

```
module Main where

import Network.SSH.Client.SimpleSSH

main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- runSimpleSSH $ openSession' "localhost" 22 Nothing
    case s of
        Left e -> print e
        Right s -> do
            r <- runSimpleSSH $ execCommand s "ls" -- hangs here
            case r of
                Left e -> print e
                Right (Result { resultOut=resultOut, resultErr=resultErr, resultExit=resultExit }) -> print resultExit
```

Is there something wrong with my Haskell code, or am I using the library wrong? I'm sure someone can tell based on the types exposed by the library.

PS: I'm actually using a [patched version of the library](http://hub.darcs.net/jp.rider/simplessh/patch/c0e1eb9d1925ff86db5d8de350af5d60123d1e55) which allows for no `known_hosts`, but the rest seems unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never used this library but looking at the documentation for `openSession`:

> Open a SSH session. The next step is to authenticate.

Also from `execCommand` description:

> One should be authenticated before sending commands on a Session.

I think your code breaks the convention by calling `execCommand` before successfully authenticating. Not sure this is the problem but looks like you need to fix that anyway.

Comment: That's what happens when you code on 2 hour of sleep. Thanks!